# how % applies to this method in Python?

Tags: python, class, string-formatting

From my studying of python, I've found two uses for %. It can be used as what's called a modulo, meaning it will divide the value to the left of it and the value to the right of it and spit back the remainder.

The other use is a string formatter. So I can do something like `'Hi there %s' % name`, where name is a list of names.

Also, if you see `%%` in a string formatting, that means a literal `%` will be entered.

Here is my question, I found this:

```
class FormatFormatStr(FormatObj):
    def __init__(self, fmt):
        self.fmt = fmt

    def tostr(self, x):
        if x is None: return 'None'
        return self.fmt%self.toval(x)
```

What does `return self.fmt%self.toval(x)` mean? It can't be a modulo because `tova`l will give me a string. It's not really a string formatter because there isn't another percent sign.

also, related to this:

```
def csvformat_factory(format):
    format = copy.deepcopy(format)
    if isinstance(format, FormatFloat):
        format.scale = 1. # override scaling for storage
        format.fmt = '%r'
    return format
```

What does the percent mean in `format.fmt = '%r'` does this mean to insert a string a la `repr()`? Or does it mean insert what the variable `r` represents? `r` in this overall program also refers to a recarray.

Thanks everyone. Hope this makes sense =)

Comment: Could you please fix the question? The "class FormatFormatStr..." should be part of the code block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string % operator is simpler than you are imagining.  It takes a string on the left side, and a variety of things on the right side.  The left side doesn't have to be a literal string, it can be a variable, or the result of another computation.  Any expression that results in a string is valid for the left side of the %.

In your first example, `self.fmt` is a string.  In order to be useful in this context, it should have a percent sign in it.

In your second example, `format.fmt` is being set to a string that would be useful as the left side of the %.  In this case, "%r" means, insert the repr() of the value into the string, as you have said.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
return self.fmt%self.toval(x)
```

`self.fmt` is a string, and that string presumably has a percent-sign placeholder in it.

`%r` in a format string is like `%s` but it prints the `repr()` of the string, so it'll have quotes and backslashes and all that.

`%` is just an operator which is just a method, and like any other method you can either pass in a literal value or a variable containing a value. In your examples they use a variable containing the format string.

Answer (score 0):

```
def tostr(self, x):
    if x is None: return 'None'
    return self.fmt%self.toval(x)
```

The `%` in this is a string formatter, definitely.  Pass the `tostr` method a formatter, eg `"%s"` or `"%r"` to see what happens

I think the `'%r'` in `csvformat_factory` is also a string formatter.  `'%r'` means take the `repr()` which is a reasonable way to display something to a user.  I imagine that `format.fmt` is used elsewhere `format.fmt % somevalue`.

Answer (score 0):

The code:
     return self.fmt % self.toval(x)

Is the "string formatting" use of the % operator, just like you suspected.

The class is handed format, which is a string containing the formatting, and when tostr(x) is called, it will return the string % x.

This is just like using % directly, only with saving the format string for later. In other words, instead of doing:

```
"I want to print the number: %n" % 20
```

What's happening is:

```
format_str = "I want to print the number: %n"
x = 20
print format_str % x
```

Which is exactly the same thing.

Comment: thansk

so lets say we have format.fmt = %r

so using the class(FormatFormatStr) and method tostr, we would eventually get '%r%format.toval(x), and supposedly x could be int or str or some format like that right?  That seems to make sense.

Comment: and that fmt would be whatever the toval(x) brings up.

Answer (score 0):

% has more than one use in string formatting.  One use is in %s, %d, etc.

Another use is to separate 'string in which we use %d and %s' from int-value and string-value.

For example

```
'string in which we use %d and %s' % (17, 'blue')
```

would result in

```
'string in which we use 17 and blue'
```

we could store 'string in which we use %d and %s' in a variable,

```
a = 'string in which we use %d and %s'
```

then

```
a % (17, 'blue')
```

results in

```
'string in which we use 17 and blue'
```

In your example
   self.fmt%self.toval(x)

self.fmt is similar to a above and self.toval(x) is (17, 'blue')